# D3 Bubble Example: What does bubble.nodes() do?

Tags: javascript, json, svg, d3.js, circle-pack

Example: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/bubble.html

[image]

I'm having a hard time understanding what goes on with line 16:

```
.data(bubble.nodes(classes(json))
```

And why, or where within the classes() function, the variable classes[] gets x,y,r values defined for each of its objects. Also, bubble.nodes() doesn't appear to be an actual function?

If I add a

```
console.log(classes)
```

between lines 44 and 45 - every object inside seems to be populated with x,y,r already -- but it is not apparent why this happens.

Comment: Did you look at the [API reference for pack.nodes](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pack-Layout#wiki-nodes)?

Comment: Yes - I did. It doesn't explain why `classes` inside the function has extra properties that are assigned before being based into bubble.nodes.

Documentation also doesn't explain the `r` attribute.

Comment: The `r` property is the node radius computed by the layout.

Comment: When - in the execution of the classes() function, are the attributes added to each of the elements in the classes[] array?

Answer (score 2):

The call to `bubble.nodes()` boils down to a call to [`d3.layout.pack().nodes()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pack-Layout#nodes) since `bubble=d3.layout.pack()`. The trick is that `pack.nodes()` is hardcoded to use the `value` key of the input's `children` (in this case all the packages) to size the nodes (add `r`) and determine position (add `x` and `y`).

In essence,

```
 var root = {"children": [
              {"packageName":"cluster","className":"AgglomerativeCluster","value":3938},
              {"packageName":"cluster","className":"CommunityStructure","value":3812},
              {"packageName":"cluster","className":"HierarchicalCluster","value":6714},
              {"packageName":"cluster","className":"MergeEdge","value":743}
         ]}; // This is an excerpt of the real data.

 var bubble = d3.layout.pack(); 

 // pack.nodes() assigns each element of "children" a r, x, and y based on value
 bubble.nodes(root);
```

This tripped me up at first as well, you can see that `classes()` doesn't add `r`, `x`, and `y` since `classes(root)` doesn't have those attributes. krasnaya's answer touched on most of this but I felt that it needed a bit more explaining (at least it did for me).

Answer (score 1):

The classes() function doesn't add the attributes.. it just flattens the tree. The attributes are added inside bubble.nodes() (which is d3.layout.pack().nodes())

```
JSON.stringify(classes[0])
"{"packageName":"cluster","className":"AgglomerativeCluster","value":3938}"
```